# How to create spring parametrized transactional test

Tags: java, spring, junit

in my tests I need use spring dependency injection transactional and parameters. I found example how to use parametrized and DI:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContextTest-business.xml" })
public class TournamentServiceTest {

@Autowired
TournamentService tournamentService;

    public TournamentServiceTest(int playerCount) {
        this.playerCount = playerCount;
    }

    @Parameters
    public static List<Object[]> data() {
        final List<Object[]> parametry = new ArrayList<Object[]>();
        parametry.add(new Object[] { 19 });
        parametry.add(new Object[] { 20 });
        return parametry;
    }

    @Before
    public void vytvorTurnaj() throws Exception {
        testContextManager = new TestContextManager(getClass());
        testContextManager.prepareTestInstance(this);
    }

@Test
public void test1() {
     Assert.assertFalse(false);
}

}
```

this example works. Now I need to add transaction to this class:

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath:applicationContextTest-business.xml" })
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TournamentServiceTest ...
```

when I add this two new line then this test thrown exception:

```
org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class org.toursys.processor.service.TournamentServiceTest]: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Superclass has no null constructors but no arguments were given
```

because he want to add empty constructor:

```
public TournamentServiceTest() {
    this.playerCount = 20;
}
```

but I cant add this because then parameterized cant run this test. How I can solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<del>The Spring TestContext Framework does currently [not support Parameterized tests](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-7731). You need a custom rule or runner for this. There is an open
[pull request](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-framework/pull/222), you can take the code from there.</del>

As of Spring [4.2](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-7731) you can use

```
@ClassRule
public static final SpringClassRule SPRING_CLASS_RULE = new SpringClassRule();

@Rule
public final SpringMethodRule springMethodRule = new SpringMethodRule();
```

Comment: hm thx then I changed concept of my test. I miss Transactional annotation and in After annotation I delete all what I changed or created in test

Answer (score 0):

I have this JUnit-runner of CallbackParams - http://callbackparams.org

It provides parameterization but it can also pass on the actual test-execution to a JUnit-runner of your choice. If you pass on to SpringJUnit4ClassRunner you will get your "spring parameterized transactional test", with transactional support etc ...

```
@RunWith(CallbackParamsRunner.class)
@WrappedRunner(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:applicationContextTest-business.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
public class TestTournamentService {

    enum PlayerCountData {
        _19, _20;

        final int value = Integer.parseInt(name().substring(1));
    }

    @ParameterizedValue PlayerCountData playerCount;

    @Autowired TournamentService tournamentService;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(
                "TournamentService should have been autowired",
                tournamentService);
        Assert.assertTrue("Player-count value greater than 18",
                18 < playerCount.value);
        Assert.assertTrue("Player-count value less than 21",
                playerCount.value < 21);
    }
}
```

As you can see the parameterization solution is a bit different. It is because CallbackParams does not give priority to parameterization of primitive data, because of reasons that are explained in the tutorials:
http://callbackparams.org/index.html#articles

With CallbackParams the parameter-values are determined from the parameter-type, so int parameterers cannot be used directly. - The above example uses parameter-type PlayerCountData and parses the int values from the names of the enum-constants.

Running the test-class results in two test-runs with these names:

- test1[playerCount=_19]
- test1[playerCount=_20]

Maybe this is what you are looking for.